# JQuery reads char code 160 instead of 32 for space from Chrome textarea

Tags: html, google-chrome

I'm having a problem with reading a text from a chrome textarea.
It works fine in firefox.
So:
1. I have a textarea with id txtText.
2. Typed three spaces (pressed spacebar three times) in the textarea.
3. Reading its value with var

```
text = $('#txtText').val().
```

1. Wrote this code:

   for( var i = 0; i < text.length; i++ ) {
   console.log(text.charAt(i) + ' ' + text.charCodeAt(i));
   }
2. That generates this:

   160
   32
   160

Please tell me what's going on.

Comment: I'm not seeing that in chrome.  Look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MzaSH/.  I'm seeing 32

Comment: I am also not seeing that.  Looking at [this](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm), it looks like 32 is a space and 160 is a non-breaking space though, so it's possible OP is pasting something into the text area that isn't just 3 spaces.

Comment: ASCII parity bit? (Not sure why Chrome would use 7-bit ASCII instead of numeric Unicode, but 160 and 32 are equivalent in ASCII.)

Comment: I repeat: I pressed the space bar three times. I did not paste some code.

Comment: Would the jquery-ui styling have anything to do with it: class="ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all"

Comment: Same code gives three 32 codes in Firefox

Comment: Can you make a fiddle that shows the problem?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/MzaSH/1/ - with jQueryUI styling - no difference.  Are you adding adding some jquery control to this element?

Comment: I tried creating a jsfiddle but it won't allow me to import the jquery and jquery ui themes ans js that I'm using

Answer (score 0):

160 is [NBSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space).

```
var p = document.createElement("P");
p.innerHTML = "&nbsp;";
alert(p.innerText.charCodeAt(0)); // 160
```